# Is it the case that adjacent odd numbers being prime is statistically independent?

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers, independence

We know that the probability that a number $n$ is prime is roughly $\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$. My question is, if $A_k$ is the event that $2k-1$ is a prime, are pairs $(A_{k}, A_{k+\Delta k})$ independent? In other words, if a certain number is prime (or not), does that change the likelihood that any surrounding odd numbers are prime? Perhaps more rigorously, as a specific example, is it true that, for almost all $k$, $\Pr[A_k | A_{k-1}] = \Pr[A_k] \sim \frac{1}{\ln(2k+1)}$?

Also, has this been proven/disproven? If not, what does the empirical evidence show?

Comment: Well...one in three consecutive odd numbers, $a,b,c$, is divisible by $3$.  knowing that, say, $a$ is prime (and greater than $3$) increases the probability that $b$ is divisible by $3$ to $\frac 12$, which would appear to imply a dependence.  Similarly for divisibility by $5 $ and so on.

Comment: The random model for the primes is that when $n$ is taken uniformly in $[1,N]$ then the $X_j=n \bmod p_j$ are independent and uniformly distributed where $p_j$ are the primes $ \le c N^{1/2}$